# How to show result into a new HTML page after calling ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling an ajax and I am able to call it successfully but I can only able to show that data in a table on the same page after hiding my form.
What I want to do is to call ajax and after success callback I want to populate that table on another page

Here is my first HTML page where I have a form to take some kind of input from user

```
    <form id="formid"  method="get">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Start Date:</h4>
            <input  type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276"
                placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required  />
            <h4>End Date:</h4>
            <input  type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276"
                placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />


            <h4>Outlets:</h4>
            <select id="all" name="outlet">
                 <option>ALL</option> 
                <c:forEach var="item" items="${obj.outlet}">
                    <option>${item}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select> 

           <div><br>
                </div>
                <div class='progress progress-striped deactive' style="background-color: white">

        <div class='progress-bar' >Loading..Please Wait...</div>
    </div>

            <div>
                <br>
 <button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and below this I am defining table tag to populate table

```
<table id="newTable" class="table table-striped" border="2" >
</table>
```

Below is my JavaScript code, which is for dynamically populating the table

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formid").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : "HourlySales",
        method : "GET",
        data : {
               fromdate : $("#startdate").val(),
               todate : $("#enddate").val(),
               outlet : $("#all").val()

             },
        success : function(tableValue) {

        console.log("test",tableValue);
        $("#formid").hide();
         addTable(tableValue)
        }
    });


    function addTable(tableValue) {
        var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]); // get all the keys from first
                                                // object
        var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
                                                            // are number
        var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
        col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


          for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
        }

});
});
```

What I want to do is define the table tag on some another html page and after click on submit button the table should populate on another html page where table tag is define. I don't want to populate the table on same page.

Comment: So why use ajax in the first place? What you describe is basic navigation on a dynamic website using GET parameters.

Comment: by ajax i am calling some JSON data.by which i am populating my table

Comment: I can see that, but it doesn't address my point at all. One specifically uses AJAX if the browser isn't supposed to navigate to another page. So instead of using AJAX, just do it the usual, basic way: just send the form to the "new HTML page" (I'm guessing PHP?) and build the table on the server.

Comment: @ChrisG no i am using java servlets and in  servlets i am only cooding for json object and then i am parsing it with help of java script.is there any whay where i am hiding form from there i can call a new page using j query

Comment: 1. use a new endpoint like `/mytable` 2. send the form there 3. in the `mytable` Servlet, use JSP templating to echo a `<script>` in your HTML that sets a few `vars` (the dates and outlet) 4. use AJAX to load the table data, then display it

Comment: Look, the main problem here is that you have a pretty big toolbox but you aren't familiar with all the tools yet. Therefore you're trying to solve any problem you encounter with the two or three tools you know how to use. This leads to a) basic but unsolvable problems like this one and b) wrong approaches, since if all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail. I recommend learning about basic dynamic website creation first. Java servlets doesn't mean you can only use static HTML and JSON.

Comment: Just make the ajax call from the same page where you want to display the content.  Trying to pass the data forward from a different page will be unnecessarily complicated at best.

Comment: @DanielBeck can you please show me some code i am very new to this thats why i have asked

Comment: @DanielBeck OP is already doing this. They want to show the table on another page though, that's why they opened the question in the first place. @ manish You seem to be ignoring me, so good luck and goodbye.

Comment: @ChrisG no brow i am following you ..why would i ignore you :(

Comment: @chrisg no, he’s not “already doing this”. He should move the Ajax call to the page on which he wants to display its results — which is what you yourself suggested, so I’m not clear why you’re now apparently arguing against it?

Comment: @DanielBeck Sorry, you're right, I misunderstood

Comment: @manishthakur Ok, so forget about AJAX for now and read this: [Servlets - Form Data](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-form-data.htm)

Comment: @ChrisG but how can i call json on my html then to populate Table?

Comment: @manishthakur Not JSON. Use `<c:forEach>` to create the table, just like you did with the options in your `<select>`. An outer loop for the rows, an inner one for the cells.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate the HTML on your site and then use a data url to show it on a new page.

Something like this:

```
function openHTML(html) {
    window.open('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html));
}
```

Or build a second page where you submit your data to.